# How to assign image src dynamically without import or component in react

Tags: reactjs

I need assistance of displaying the images without import or any external component. I have tried all the below methods but nothing worked out. Any assistance on this matter is much appreciated.

When i use require(), I get the error a Cannot find module '../assets/images/products

```
import React from "react";
    
export default function ProductGallery() {
  const products = [
    {
      ProductImage: "../assets/images/products/image1.jpg",
    },
    {
      ProductImage: "../assets/images/products/image2.jpg",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="row">
      {products.map((item, index) => (
        <div className="galleryBox" key={index}>
          <img src={require(item.ProductImage)}/>
          <img src={require(""+item.ProductImage)}/>
          <img src={require(`${item.ProductImage}`)}/>
          // all the three methods didnt work
          <img src={item.ProductImage}/>
          // this doesnt show image at all. When I Inspect, it shows the path correct. But it should come from ../static, however it showing actual path
        </div>
      ))}
    <div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the image in the Public folder, so that, the reference path can pull the image.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, unfortunately `require` function does not accept dynamic resources. The problem is related to the fact `require` function will be loaded before runtime and, if it doesn't find a resource at that time, it doesn't work.

A possible workaround is made an object with all the resources you need like:

```
export default resources = {
   image1: require('../assets/images/products/image1.jpg'),
   image2: require('../assets/images/products/image2.jpg')
}
```

Then import this object in your component and use it like this:

```
<img src={resources.image1}/>
<img src={resources.image2}/>
```

It's the only way I found to have dynamic resources with `require` function.

Comment: export default resources = {
   image1: require('../assets/images/products/image1.jpg'),
   image2: require('../assets/images/products/image2.jpg')
}

But that's coming it will be coming from the backend. I will assign this to the data coming from the backend later.

Comment: in that case, i might not be able to use require

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What is coming from backed? `resources` it's just an object that you could initialized in a separated file of your project and import in component in which you need to show image1 or image2.

Comment: i will get this image resource as a json data from my api. so the json data will look something like the products array.

Comment: Ok understood. The problem becames harder. But let me understand better: you have your images in '../assets/images/products/image1.jpg' that si a folder in your project and then you asking to the backend to provides you the path to these resources correct?

Comment: Absolutely correct. The backend will provide JSON of the path and the ../assets/images/products/image1 is a folder that i have in frontend

Comment: Ok, I don't know maybe the solution you made it's to much complicated for your scope. It's just my opinion, but why ask to backend for a resource already present in your local folder? I don't want to say that your solution is not applicable for require because I'm not so expert (and maybe there is another way) but maybe you could simplyfy. Or you could do something like: ask to your backend the resources you need. In the same time you have done the object I wrote on answer, then write a condition like `if (answerfrombacked === "image1") { assign to img resource.image1 } else ...`. Could work.