# Image require with variable path not working

Tags: reactjs

Actually trying to check if file(image) exists to add it to render.

Confused that this code works

```
let i = 2;
let s = require('../../public' + this.cardData.image.optional_path + '-' + i + '.jpg');
```

and as a result s = Module

And this one produce an error

```
let i = 2;
let path = '../../public' + this.cardData.image.optional_path + '-' + i + '.jpg';
let z = require(path);
```

Error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../../public/images/catgory1/images-2.jpg'
```

Did i missed something ?

Comment: Might it be releated to webpack, or something that fails to correctly parse require patch?

Comment: @majkrzak not sure what are you talking about

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171142/importing-image-dynamically-react-js-require-img-path-cannot-find-module could help?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito nope. i need to build a list of images (for corousel) that exists. linked article displays image without checking.

Comment: @Subdigger I already had a problem like that and it was related to the dynamic part of the image link. Have you tried to define a static list of available images like https://stackoverflow.com/a/63430097/13897065 ?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito as you can see in question - tere 2 way of doing the same. upper one is work fine. even if i declara it full text path it works fine. but i can not declare all imeges. names come from apy request.